# Spring Integration Concurrent JMS adapter

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration (3.0.6) and having problems using a `message-driven-channel-adapter` concurrently.  If I send 2 jobs to the JMS queue and ensure the first one never finishes (kept in a loop) the second job is never taken from the queue.

If I remove the `transaction-manager` from the channel adapter I get the concurrency I expect.  Does anybody see anything wrong with the way I am configuring this?

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter 
    channel="jobsChannel" 
    connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
    pub-sub-domain="false"
    destination-name="JOBS_QUEUE" 
    transaction-manager="jmsTxManager"
    concurrent-consumers="5"
    max-messages-per-task="1"
    error-channel="errorChannel"
    id="jobJmsReceiver" />

<amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="true"> 
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:0" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTxManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have to see DEBUG logs, but you really don't need a transaction manager, set `acknowledge="transacted"` and the container will use local transactions on the session.

You typically only need an external transaction manager when synchronizing transactions (e.g. with a JDBC tm) or when using a JTA transaction manager in an app server.

Comment: Thank you, this fits my use case and works concurrently